# Better WP security blocking access to a php loading info from other site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security

I have a problem with Better WP security that it blocks access to a custom php script which loads in data to sidebar.php from an external website through a php script http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ in the root folder together with the loader custom .php
I get Warning: include(my.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in theme-path/sidebar.php on line 7
I think some tweak needs to be adde in .htacces to allow this inclusion, if I'm correct the .htaccess blocks the .php requests in the theme path, but how can I whitelist only this file that it is correctly included?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the .htaccess, but the new version of the iThemes Security blocking the htttp: in the include() command, so I put ini_set("allow_url_include", 1); before it and used the absolute server path to the .php file. works like a charm… :-)